# Physics.Raycast Return unexpected result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my experimentation I am moving small cube to right x direction in that case.
Ray start and end related small cube and it moves with small cube as in image.
I am getting hit distance of ray to the big cube.

Distance looks normal. But the distance became 0 at this instance at the image.
It should be 0 when ray reached end of big cube. Why is that happening?

I am using following code;

```
private void GetMiddleDist()
{

    middleDist = 0f;
    Ray ray = new (middle1.transform.position, middle2.transform.position);
    Debug.DrawLine(middle1.transform.position, middle2.transform.position, Color.red);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, 0.7f))
    {
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("world"))
        { 
            middleDist = hit.distance;
        }
    }


}
```

I used children of empties  of small cube for the start and end of ray.
And ray moves as it looks like in image.

[image: Ray Placement]

Comment: you are providing two positions in Ray constructor. You should provide a position and a direction like so: `Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);`

Comment: Second position is the direction.

Comment: And it is wrong practice of course thx.

Comment: For the future know: There is also [`Debug.DrawRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) ;)

Comment: Did you debug to see what collider it actually hit?  I see the tag check, but do other objects in the scene have the same tag?  Is it possible it hit something unexpected?

Comment: @avariant, I did not need to debug because after I changed Ray statement like rustyBucketBay suggested it is started to return values expected.